# I need some plugin which can Trigger a jenkins build upon successful completion of a bamboo job

Tags: jenkins, soapui, bamboo

Basically i need to create a jenkins job which can check the latest builds on bamboo and once the war is ready it should invoke the test suites in SoapUI 
can someone tell me what is the Simplest way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to have a look at the [FSTrigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin) or [scriptTrigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin) or URLTrigger same kind of url